# How to set theme of a CommandBarFlyout in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

there is not Presenter Style or Requested Theme option to CommandBarFlyout in XAML or C#. So how to set dark or light theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CommandBarFlyout is a new XAML control just introduced in update 1809 and MS hasn't already included the Style nor RequestedTheme properties.

**For now, the CommandBarFlyout inherits its parent's theme**, that's all.

If you have to associate the CommandBarFlyout to an Image control, for example, then you can change the image's theme without any problem, because it wouldn't change anything in the main controls itself.

For more infos about this control and the other ones, just download the companion app from the Windows Store: *XAML Controls Gallery*.  (Store link: [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MSVH128X2ZT))

Best Regards